# Typescript array with function indexer

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to save some functions into an array and get them with the same function. Need a function or function reference, not string as indexer for an array.

```
myArray: SomeClass[] = [];
myArray[func].func = func;
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as written. Property names in JavaScript are always strings. You'll have to write the lookup code yourself (e.g. using parallel arrays).